# ASP.net GridView Handle Sorting

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have the following and I'm not sure how to implement the sorting function on the gridview?  The data and paging work fine. Just not sure how to handle the sorting method?  I simply want to sort columns by asc and desc.

```
 public partial class inLinksAuthGrid : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(LoadSomeData));
    }

    public async Task LoadSomeData()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test");
            var myInLinks = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://inlink-xxxxxx.net:5000/inlinks");

            await Task.WhenAll(myInLinks);
            var links = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(await myInLinks);

            GridView1.DataSource = links.inlinks;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO:
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    }

    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        // WHAT do I do here?
    }

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Inlink[] inlinks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Inlink
    {
        public string clicks { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string ip { get; set; }
        public string keyword { get; set; }
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }
}


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" Width="900" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" AllowSorting="True"></asp:GridView>
```

Everything works just have no idea how to get sorting to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `allowsorting` property of the gridview to `true` like `allowsorting="true"` since you are trying to sort the column by asc/desc. See [GridView.AllowSorting Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting(v=vs.110).aspx)